# Searching and deleting a node from JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

JSON is holding a data.

1. I need to remove the node where the "id" value matches passed in value. In the below code `var isRemoved = (dataDeserialized as JArray).Remove(index);` is returning false. The node is not deleted. How can i delete the node?
2. The property name "id" is even dynamic. It will get passed in. How can i check the property name along with value (current) to find the index?

Here is what i have so far:

```
var entityJson = @"
            [
              {
                'id': 1,
                'code': 'abc1'
              },
              {
                'id': 2,
                'code': 'abc2'
              }
            ]".Replace("'", "\"");

            var dataDeserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(entityJson);// DataLoader.DeserializeJson(entityJson, false);

            if(dataDeserialized.Count > 0)
            {
                var key = "id";
                var value = "2";
                var index = 0;
                var isFound = false;

                foreach(var d in dataDeserialized)
                {
                    if((string)d.id == value.ToString())
                    {
                        isFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    index++;
                }

                if (isFound)
                {
                    var isRemoved = (dataDeserialized as JArray).Remove(index);
                    if (isRemoved)
                    {
                        var setting = new JsonSerializerSettings
                        {
                            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
                        };
                        var resul = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataDeserialized, setting);
                        //var result = JsonHelper.SerializeObject(dataDeserialized);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have tried jObject as well but it is giving an error `Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 2, position 13`

```
dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(entityJson);
(obj.employees as JArray).RemoveAt(0);
```

**Update #1:** here is what worked for me for #1 above

```
if(dataDeserialized.Count > 0)
            {
                var key = "id";
                var value = "2";

                JArray list = new JArray();

                foreach (var d in dataDeserialized)
                {
                    if ((string)d.id != value.ToString())
                    {
                        list.Add(d);
                    }
                }

                if(list.Count > 0)
                {
                    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
                }
            }
```

Still, how can i do #2, checking the "key"?

Comment: Are you creating your JSON in code like that?  If so, why?  As for the "remove" problem, I _highly_ recommend you create a class that represents the structure instead of using dynamic, that way you can easily use LINQ to filter the original collection and re-serialize

Comment: I'll get a path to the json file, it is like a repository. The code needs to run on any json file.  The key and value will get passed in as well. I cannot create a class out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to deserialize this json to a strongly typed object, I would recommend working with the `JObject` and `JArray` classes from the `Newtonsoft.Json` package because they are much more flexible for this purpose.

So you can easily remove a node from the json with a dynamic key like this:

```cs
    string key = "id";
    int id = 2;

    var entityJson = @"
    [
        {
            ""id"": 1,
            ""code"": ""abc1""
        },
        {
            ""id"": 2,
            ""code"": ""abc2""
        },
        {
            ""id"": 3,
            ""code"": ""abc3""
        }
    ]";

    JArray jarray = JArray.Parse(entityJson);

    var item = jarray.Children().Where(i => (int)(i as JObject).GetValue(key) == id).SingleOrDefault();

    if (item != null)
    {
        jarray.Remove(item);
    }

    var resul = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jarray);
```